# How to change the background color and text color with the click of a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change three different paragraphs into colors that are following the same theme but different(not apparent  in example, just a test). I can't get them to change however. :( I'm also willing to use a JQuery way of doing it.

HTML

```
<button onclick="white()">
        <p>White</p>
    </button>

    <button onclick="red()">
        <p>Red</p>
    </button>

    <button onclick="yellow()">
        <p>Yellow</p>
    </button>

    <button onclick="blue()">
        <p>Blue</p>
    </button>

    <h1>Hey There</h1>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Colors are cool</li>
        <li>Join the Rebellion!!!</li>
    </ul>


    <div class="colorbox" id="colorbox1">
        <h1>Div one</h1>
        <p>I'm 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="colorbox" id="colorbox2">
        <h1>Div two</h1>
        <p>I'm 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="colorbox" id="colorbox3">
        <h1>Div three</h1>
        <p>I'm 3</p>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var colorbox1 = document.getElementsById('colorbox1');
var colorbox2 = document.getElementsById('colorbox2');
var colorbox3 = document.getElementsById('colorbox3');

function white() {
    colorbox1.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    colorbox1.style.color = "black";

    colorbox2.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    colorbox2.style.color = "black";

    colorbox3.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    colorbox3.style.color = "black";
}

function red() {
    colorbox1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    colorbox1.style.color = "black";

    colorbox2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    colorbox2.style.color = "black";

    colorbox3.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    colorbox3.style.color = "black";
}

function yellow() {
    colorbox1.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    colorbox1.style.color = "black";

    colorbox2.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    colorbox2.style.color = "black";

    colorbox3.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    colorbox3.style.color = "black";
}

function blue() {
    colorbox1.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    colorbox1.style.color = "black";

    colorbox2.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    colorbox2.style.color = "black";

    colorbox3.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    colorbox3.style.color = "black";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `getElementsById()` method, only `getElementById()` without `s`

```
var colorbox1 = document.getElementById('colorbox1');
var colorbox2 = document.getElementById('colorbox2');
var colorbox3 = document.getElementById('colorbox3');
```

Answer (score 1):

JQUERY way to deal with it:
First of all I would have only one function. Just give it the color in parameter for example

```
onclick="changeColor('#3E6AA9')" //for blue
```

Here's a full code (didn't deal with background)

```
<button onclick="changeColor('#fff')">
        <p>White</p>
    </button>

    <button onclick="changeColor('#D80000')">
        <p>Red</p>
    </button>

    <button onclick="changeColor('#FBD505')">
        <p>Yellow</p>
    </button>

    <button onclick="changeColor('#0086BE')">
        <p>Blue</p>
    </button>

    <h1>Hey There</h1>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Colors are cool</li>
        <li>Join the Rebellion!!!</li>
    </ul>


    <div class="colorbox" id="colorbox1">
        <h1>Div one</h1>
        <p>I'm 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="colorbox" id="colorbox2">
        <h1>Div two</h1>
        <p>I'm 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="colorbox" id="colorbox3">
        <h1>Div three</h1>
        <p>I'm 3</p>
    </div>
    <script>
    function changeColor(color){
console.log(color);
$('.colorbox').css({'color': color});
}
    </script>
```

Check this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/tqVUp/37/)

Comment: @cosmichero 2025, Let me know if you need explain on this code, I'll edit it

Comment: I understand the code but for my specific needs i only needed the div's to change. The code i put was only like a test for a larger project im working on. I just had an extra s in the getElementById but I like your answer to :D

Comment: Now that I have that working I gotta work on the slow animations for the colors